# Quick and Easy way to Add Search to the P2 Theme?

Tags: search, theme-p2

Out of the box the [P2 Theme](http://p2theme.com) does not have search. Is there a quick and easy way to add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native search widget?

[Google Custom Search Element](http://www.google.com/webelements/#show-custom-search) is also quite easy to implement, but won't fit private site.

Comment: Doh! I'm just so unused to using Widgets because they are not a good fit for my clients requirements and thus I forget about them.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can always search in wordpress site by adding a `GET` parameter `"?s="`

for example: `www.example.com/?s=search-phrase`

So if you make some form, with simple input of `name="s"` and with method "get" you are done.